# how to implement datetime functions using class

Tags: python, datetime

In the code that I wrote, I keep on repeating the same code which makes no sense of using a class. I would like to use  if possible the timedate variable in all the method instead of keep on re rewritting the date in every method.

```
from datetime import  datetime, date, time
import time

class Nov420:
    def __init__(self, timedate):
        self.timedate=timedate

    @property
    def dateformat1(self):
        self.d=datetime(2020, 11, 4, 14, 53, 00)
        return self.d.strftime('%y/%b/%d %H:%M:%S ')
    @property
    def dateformat2(self):
        self.d=datetime(2020, 11, 4, 14, 53, 00 )
        return self.d.strftime('%Y/%B/%d %H:%M:%S %p')

    @property
    def wday1(self):
        self.d=datetime(2020, 11, 4, 14, 53, 00)
        return self.d.strftime('%a, %Y %b %d ')

    @property
    def wday2(self):
        self.d = datetime(2020, 11, 4, 14, 53, 00)
        return self.d.strftime('%A, %Y %b %d ')

    @property
    def weekday(self):
        self.d = datetime(2020, 11, 4, 14, 53, 00)
        return self.d.isoweekday()

    @property
    def day_of_yr(self):
        self.d = datetime(2020, 11, 4, 14, 53, 00)
        self.d = time.gmtime(self.d.timestamp())
        return self.d[7]


date1=datetime(2020, 11, 4, 14, 53)
nov=Nov420(date1)
print(nov.dateformat1)
print(nov.dateformat2)
print(nov.wday1)
print(nov.wday2)
print(nov.weekday)
print(nov.day_of_yr)
```

result:

```
2020/11/04 14:53:00
20/November/04 14:53:00 PM
Wed, 2020 Nov 04
Wednesday, 2020 November 04
Weekday: 3
Day of the year: 309
Week number of the year: 44
```

Comment: Why do you have the same date inside the methods that you pass into the `__init__()` method? Did you mean (eg dateformat1) `return self.timedate.strftime('%y/%b/%d %H:%M:%S ')`?

Comment: Move `self.d=datetime(2020, 11, 4, 14, 53, 00 )` into `__init__`, then re-use `self.d` on the methods.

Comment: That being said, making `Nov420` a class doesn't make a lot of sense. Classes should be thought of as *categories of things*. You should just have something like `class MyDate` (with a better name) and then acccept the date as an argument, that you assign to `self.d`, then the moethds yuse that. Then you can do something like `nov420 = MyDate(datetime(2020, 11, 4, 14, 53))` or `oct3021 = MyDate(datetime(2021, 10, 30, 11, 53))`